# Is it possible to make browsers avoid showing you sites from a customized list within the search results?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet, browser, web-filtering

I hate it when some sites appear again and again within my google (or any other search engine) list.

For instance, you may go to google image search and type in "samurai soldier with sword". The results list is infected with sites trying to sell you such images. You can combat this by adding their names preceded by a minus sign every time you do a search. But the list can become enormous, and repeating the process every time is really annoying, tiring, and time consuming:

> "samurai soldier with sword" -depositphotos.com -graphicleftovers.com
>   -123rf.com

Is not there any *free* firefox plugin or something that allows me to add "123rf.com" **just once and for all** in some kind of filter list, and from that moment **never** see it again in any of my future search results, as if the site had been completely wiped out of existence?

Comment: I manually migrated this question from another SE site, where it was closed. In the text, they recommended me to post it here, so I have rewritten it here and deleted the old one there.

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10522/can-i-exclude-spam-domains-from-my-search-results

Answer (score 4):

### Firefox

I believe this [`addon`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (*Greasemonkey*) should do the job for you. After installing the extension use this [`script`](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/95205)(Search Filter / Block Sites).

Once installed, you can easily add to your blocked sites list, clicking directly on a button **Block** that appears next to each search result on Google.(See image below).

[image]

---

### Google Chrome

For *Google Chrome* has an extension [`Personal Blocklist (by Google)`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) to make this work.

> The extension will transmit to Google Personal Blocklist the domains
>   you decide to block. When you decide to lock or unlock a domain, the
>   extension will also transmit to Google the URL of the page where the
>   results are shown locked or unlocked.

[image]

---

### Opera

This [`addon`](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/google-search-results-blocker/)(*Google search results blocker*) that  works similarly to [`Google Chrome's Personal Blocklist extension`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef).
You can remove google search results on a per *hostname/wildcard basis*.

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks, but (at least the firefox solution) does only filter search web results, but not image search results. I mean, when you directly look for images in google (go to www.google.com and click on "images" on top of the page, before entering any text)